# Remove fisheye distortion when calculating vectors for raymarching

Tags: c, opencl, raymarching

I am trying to write an opencl kernel for raymarching. Everything works except there is noticeable fisheye distortion in the resulting images, as seen in this example: (This is supposed to be a cube)

[image]

The problem lies in the way I construct the direction vector for each ray.

Currently, I give the kernel the camera's direction as pitch and yaw (`pitch` and `yaw` in my code).

Then based on the fov (`fov`), coordinates of the pixel that the kernel is calculating (`ix` and `iy`) and the width and height of the entire frame (`width`, `height`) I get the pitch and yaw for the direction of the ray.

Finally I construct a unit vector using the pitch and yaw given by the previous calculations.

(`varfloat` represents either float or double depending on whether the kernel is run with double or single floating point precision)

For the image above, `fov` was Pi/3 and `width` and `height` were both 500.

```c
unsigned int ix = get_global_id(0);
unsigned int iy = get_global_id(1);

//PROBLEM LIES IN THESE 3 LINES:

varfloat y = yaw - fov/2.0 + fov*ix/width; //get yaw using horizontal fov
varfloat f = (fov * height) / width;       //calculate vertical fov from horizontal fov scaled proportionally based on width and height
varfloat p = pitch - f/2.0 + f*iy/height;  //get pitch using vertical fov

varfloat3 direction = {sin(y)*cos(p), cos(y)*cos(p), sin(p)}; //unit vector for ray direction
```

Can someone tell me how I should be calculating the pitch and yaw for the direction vector in order to eliminate the distortion?

Comment: your pitch formula seems odd expanding `p` we get `p = pitch - f/2.0 + (fov * height)/width *iy/height`? => `p = pitch - f/2.0 + fov *iy / width` ? that doesn't seem right.

Comment: what happens when pitch = yaw = 0?

Comment: when both pitch and yaw are 0 direction vector is {0, 1, 0}. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the pitch formula seeming odd.